# remove characters from a string after a dot(.)

Tags: string

Can anyone tell me how to remove characters from a string after a particular character, in my case DOT(.)

e.g.

**08:27:26.187Z** i want to remove all the characters after DOT(.)

Thanks

Comment: any specific language?

Comment: If you specify a language I'm sure you can find that this has already been asked.

Answer (score 1):

In java, to remove the characters *after* a dot:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\..*", ".");
```

and to remove the characters *including* the dot:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\..*", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the string starting from the back counting every character that is NOT a dot until you reach one or you have read the entire string. If you encouter a dot you delete the last x characters. Depending on the language used there can be multiple ways of doing that. (In C you could even simply replace the dot character with a '\0' character if you don't care about memory waste ;)

Answer (score 1):

In c#

```
var str = "08:27:26.187Z";
str = str.split(".")[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

In C you could use the strstr function to find the pointer to the first . character and then use that address to terminate the string, I'm assuming that you want to discard the . character too.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define DELIMITER_CHAR  "."

int main ( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    char a[] = "08:27:26.187Z";
    char *ptr = NULL;

    printf( "Original string: %s\n", a );

    ptr = strstr ( a, DELIMITER_CHAR );

    *ptr = '\0';

    printf( "Corrected string: %s\n", a );

    return 0;
}
```